# JSONata transformation script for taking source as it is with some override/modifications

Tags: jsonata

I have JSON, for example:

```
{
 "PDMSReferenceNumber": "11340",
 "OntologyClass": "rdl:P101003917",
 "TopTag": "DEEP1",
 "ServiceDescription2": "Main manual",
 "SystemVoltagePrimaryWinding": "",
 "ClearOpeningHeight": "true"
}
```

Is it possible to create JSONata script like this:

```
{
  "*": *,
  "MainTag": TopTag
}
```

The result should be

```
{
 "PDMSReferenceNumber": "11340",
 "OntologyClass": "rdl:P101003917",
 "ServiceDescription2": "Main manual",
 "SystemVoltagePrimaryWinding": "",
 "ClearOpeningHeight": "true",
 "MainTag": "DEEP1"
}
```

So I want to take the source JSON is it is and make some override and modifications.

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the Transform Function - https://docs.jsonata.org/other-operators#-------transform

So this basic "copys" TopTag to MainTag, and adds to object and then deletes TopTag

```
$ ~> |$|{'MainTag': TopTag}, ['TopTag']|
```

Here you go to show it:
https://try.jsonata.org/YqpO6oUk9

Comment: Nice! It is  what I was looking for! Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what JSONata does for you "transform" JSON.

You can simply do this:

```
$.{
"MainTag": TopTag,
"PDMSReferenceNumber": PDMSReferenceNumber,
"OntologyClass": OntologyClass,
"ServiceDescription2": ServiceDescription2,
"SystemVoltagePrimaryWinding": SystemVoltagePrimaryWinding,
"ClearOpeningHeight": ClearOpeningHeight
}
```

So the left part is the "key" for your new object, and the right is the "Key" from your source JSON (hence we have "MainTag": TopTag)

Comment: I understand how JSONata works, but I am asking about a "command" which can take json as it is and modify some props only.

Comment: There are commands to add/remove/rename keys from the JSON that I am aware off.

If you wanted to create a rule engine to do this you could, here is a basic example:

```